# regex to delete specific entries in .css file

Tags: css, .net

trying to delete the following entries in a .css file

```
UNUSEDbody.sticky-menu-active {
    padding-top: 26px;
}
```

all the css entries I want to remove are prefixed with UNUSED followed by characters `{ }`

so I want to delete everything starting with `UNUSED` and including the declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in javascript:

```
var text = "...";
var regex = /^UNUSED[^{]*?{[^}]*}[\r\n ]*/gm;
console.log(text.replace(regex, ''));
```

You should be more specific about regex and css. Are you trying to run some command in `cmd/sh` to remove these entries from file, or you are trying to do that from you code?

Comment: thanks. trying to do a find and replace in Visual Studio. Entered the expression but does not find anything

Comment: are you using vs 2015? Older VS used different "regex" format.

Comment: works. I removed the '/' from each end..awesome. thanks

Comment: Yes, you don't need `//gm` stuff around regex in VS.